# What would the rough hash rate for an ec2 instance be - litecoin

Tags: litecoin

High-CPU Extra Large Instance

7 GiB of memory

20 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 2.5 EC2 Compute Units each)

1690 GB of instance storage

64-bit platform

I/O Performance: High

EBS-Optimized Available: 1000 Mbps

API name: c1.xlarge

Above is the specification for an Amazon EC2 instance, I was just wondering if there is any information on what the hash rate would be for litecoins on this Amazon EC2 instance.

Is there any calculations you can use to find out the hash rate from the GHz of a processor?
I know none f the other specs apart from the processor really matter but I'm just not sure what the GHz for the EC2 processor would be.

Comment: so have you tried it by yourself? what is the result if you had?

Comment: You're wasting money on the I/O performance and storage.

Comment: Yeah, don't do this, it won't be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be as high as you expect with out compiling CPUMINER for multi core.
I can not tell if the last on the list is the same or a slower version of what you are referring to from this list online.

http://litecoin.info/Mining_Hardware_Comparison#Other
based on that page, each Amazon High-CPU Extra Large Instance, running Ubuntu 12.04.1 and using pooler's cpuminer 2.2.3, has a script hash rate of 38 Khash/second. Rounding down ( habbit, no real math reason other than the real world is usually slower ) to 19 times that makes it an estimated 722  Khash/second and possibly faster.